# using fs.existsSync...I am unable to get true as the output...(edited)

Tags: node.js, path, fs

In the below code,
I am unzipping a folder and after Unzipping validating files in it. I can manually see the files in my mac, however, though code i am not able assert it. `fs.existsSync` asserts it to be false.

```
const zipFilePath = path.join(zipDirPath, `webfontkit${params.tc}.zip`);
const unzipFolderPath = path.join(outDir, `webfontkit${params.tc}`);

// Execute request for kit API and save response zip files
await utils.executeRequestAndSaveReponseInFileSystem(params,
    zipFilePath);

// Unzip the zip files downloaded
let unzipper = new DecompressZip( zipFilePath );
unzipper.extract({
    path: unzipFolderPath
}); 

// await utils.unzipFolder(zipFilePath, unzipFolderPath);
//
// await expect(fs.existsSync(unzipFolderPath)).toEqual(true);

const kitname = await utils
    .replaceDelimitter(params.body.kitName, ' ', '_');

const kitPath = path.join(unzipFolderPath, kitname);
console.log(kitPath);

// Verify kitpath and kitname exists
await expect(fs.existsSync(kitPath)).toEqual(true);
await expect(fs.existsSync(path.join(kitPath, `${kitname}.css`))).toEqual(true);
```

Here's another version based on feedback so far:

```
static async unzipFolder(zipFilePath, unzipFolderPath) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
         fs.createReadStream(zipFilePath)
            .pipe(unzip.Extract({ path: unzipFolderPath }))
            .on('close', () => {     
                resolve();
                
            })
            .on('error', (error) => {
                reject(error);
                
            });
    });
}


await utils.unzipFolder(zipFilePath, unzipFolderPath);



await expect(fs.existsSync(unzipFolderPath)).toEqual(true);
        
const kitname = await utils
    .replaceDelimitter(params.body.kitName, ' ', '_');

const kitPath = path.join(unzipFolderPath, kitname);
console.log(kitPath,'KITPATH');
console.log(kitname,'KITNAME');

await utils.getFile(unzipFolderPath,50000);

// Verify kitpath and kitname exists
await expect(fs.existsSync(kitPath)).toEqual(true);
await expect(fs.existsSync(path.join(kitPath, `${kitname}.css`))).toEqual(true);
```

Comment: What's the output of kitpath

Comment: What is `DecompressZip`? It's probably async.

Comment: Isn't `unzipper.extract()` asynchronous?  If so, you have to wait for it to finish before examining results.

Comment: @PDHide the out put is output/webfontkit1/SampleKit

Comment: @jfriend00 i have replaced with async/await now...still not resolved for me

Comment: I tried to fix your code formatting so I could read it.  What is the exact problem with the 2nd version?

Comment: the problem is same...the files available on the sytem yet the test fails...either the kit takes longer to unzip and assertion is happening before that..But precisely for that reason Async/await is used....but to no respite...cant figure out now..should writing the code synchronously work..thinking of that or changing the libraries and functions used @jfriend00

Comment: P.S Sorry that u had to do the formatting.. @jfriend00

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `fs.existsSync()` long before the unzip operation has completed and thus the file is not there yet.

If you look at [the doc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/decompress-zip) for the library that it looks like you're using, then `unzipper.extract()` is ***asynchronous***.  When you call it, that just starts the operation and then returns immediately and it finishes sometime later.

You need to install event handlers to see when it's actually done.  The code in the doc shows:

```
unzipper.on('extract', function (log) {
    console.log('Finished extracting');
    expect(fs.existsSync(kitPath)).toEqual(true);
});
```

To see when it's actually done unzipping.  Inside of that callback is where you should be calling `fs.existsSync()`.

---

I attempted to make a reproducible version of your code that I could run on my own system.  Here's what I have and it works just fine.  I used some random ZIP file I had lying around on my system that had a bunch of images in it.  I picked the filename of one of those images and coded it into the program to test if it exists.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const unzipper = require('unzipper');
const path = require('path');

async function unzipFolder(zipFilePath, unzipFolderPath) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        fs.createReadStream(zipFilePath)
            .pipe(unzipper.Extract({ path: unzipFolderPath }))
            .on('close', resolve)
            .on('error', reject);
    });
}

async function run() {

    const zipFilePath = "./test.zip";        // sample input zip file
    const unzipFolderPath = "./unzip";       // directory to put unzipped contents into

    await unzipFolder(zipFilePath, unzipFolderPath);

    console.log("fs.existsSync(unzipFolderPath)", fs.existsSync(unzipFolderPath));

    const testFileName = path.join(unzipFolderPath, "20200610_122443.jpg");

    // Verify expected output file exists
    console.log("fs.existsSync(testFileName)", fs.existsSync(testFileName));
}

run().then(result => {
    console.log("success");
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

This code works.  It generates this output:

```
fs.existsSync(unzipFolderPath) true
fs.existsSync(testFileName) true
success
```

Comment: I have used following function now with async/ await..... but to no respite....

Comment: static async unzipFolder(zipFilePath, unzipFolderPath) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
             fs.createReadStream(zipFilePath)
                .pipe(unzip.Extract({ path: unzipFolderPath, }).on('close',()=>{resolve();}))
                // .on('finish', () => {     
                //     resolve();
                    
                // })
                .on('error', (error) => {
                    reject(error);
                    
                });
        });
    }

Comment: await utils.unzipFolder(zipFilePath, unzipFolderPath);
           console.log(unzipFolderPath,'UNZIP')
            
            const kitname = await utils
                .replaceDelimitter(params.body.kitName, ' ', '_');

            const kitPath = path.join(unzipFolderPath, kitname);

            await utils.getFile(kitPath,5000);

            // Verify kitpath and kitname exists
            await expect(fs.existsSync(kitPath)).toEqual(true);
            await expect(fs.existsSync(path.join(kitPath, `${kitname}.css`))).toEqual(true);

Comment: @nps -  Multiline code in comments is not readable.  If you're trying to show me a subsequent effort to fix, then ADD it to the end of your question (do not remove or overwrite or replace anything in the original question) and then leave me a comment here that you've added onto the end of your question your current implementation and describe what you are still having trouble with.

Comment: added an async/await now...still facing the same issue....  @jfriend00

Comment: @nps - I added a stand-alone runnable version of your code to my answer that works just fine for me.  Since you don't disclose everything needed to run your code, I had to simplify in a few ways to make it separately runnable, but maybe you can build off this working code and find out where your precise setup goes haywire.

Comment: @nps - Did this help you figure things out?  If so, you can indicate that to the community by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer and that will also earn you some reputation points here for following the proper procedure.